# Unintended consequences when changing next line of execution in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

Why does this go BOOM?

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace Test
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                // 1. Hit F10 to step into debugging.
                string[] one = {"1"}; //2. Drag arrow to make this next statement executed
                // 3. Hit f5.
                Enumerable.Range(1,1)
                    .Where(x => one.Contains(x.ToString()));
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Console.Write("BOOM!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Exception is "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: You should add that to the question, not in a comment.

Comment: Unable to reproduce the error. What IDE are you using?

Comment: I reproduced it with VS2013.  Very weird indeed.

Comment: Try `Console.Write(ex.ToString());`

Comment: I'm using VS2012 Ultimate - cannot reproduce.

Comment: This was with VS2013 professional (Update 4).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the ILDASM output, there might be an explanation here...

```
  .locals init ([0] class Test.Program/'<>c__DisplayClass1' 'CS$<>8__locals2',
           [1] class [mscorlib]System.Exception exception,
           [2] string[] CS$0$0000)
  IL_0000:  nop
  .try
  {
    IL_0001:  newobj     instance void Test.Program/'<>c__DisplayClass1'::.ctor()
    IL_0006:  stloc.0
    IL_0007:  nop
    IL_0008:  ldloc.0
    IL_0009:  ldc.i4.1
    IL_000a:  newarr     [mscorlib]System.String
    IL_000f:  stloc.2
    IL_0010:  ldloc.2
    IL_0011:  ldc.i4.0
    IL_0012:  ldstr      "1"
    IL_0017:  stelem.ref
    IL_0018:  ldloc.2
    IL_0019:  stfld      string[] Test.Program/'<>c__DisplayClass1'::one
    IL_001e:  ldc.i4.1
    IL_001f:  ldc.i4.1
    IL_0020:  call       class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<int32> [System.Core]System.Linq.Enumerable::Range(int32,
                                                                                                                                    int32)
    IL_0025:  ldloc.0
    IL_0026:  ldftn      instance bool Test.Program/'<>c__DisplayClass1'::'<Main>b__0'(int32)
    IL_002c:  newobj     instance void class [mscorlib]System.Func`2<int32,bool>::.ctor(object,
                                                                                        native int)
    IL_0031:  call       class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<!!0> [System.Core]System.Linq.Enumerable::Where<int32>(class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<!!0>,
                                                                                                                                         class [mscorlib]System.Func`2<!!0,bool>)
    IL_0036:  pop
    IL_0037:  nop
    IL_0038:  leave.s    IL_004a
  }  // end .try
  catch [mscorlib]System.Exception 
  {
```

When you drag the execution cursor, you run the risk of corrupting the call stack. This is because dragging the cursor literally skips those lines. When running in the debugger, after hitting F10, the cursor stops at the start of the `Main` routine, before the try. If you drag the cursor to the creation of the array, you are skipping this fun line:

`IL_0001:  newobj     instance void Test.Program/'<>c__DisplayClass1'::.ctor()`

Which creates an instance of the `Program` class. The program class is then used later here:

`IL_0019:  stfld      string[] Test.Program/'<>c__DisplayClass1'::one`

Which because you skipped it, didn't create that object, so you get a `NullReferenceException` when running.

Why people can't reproduce this on VS2012, I'm not sure. Maybe the compiler is outputting different IL, but this is far as I can come up with using VS2013 Ultimate and C#4.5.

Interestingly enough, when you comment out the try/catch, the start of the program in IL looks like this:

```
.locals init ([0] class Test.Program/'<>c__DisplayClass1' 'CS$<>8__locals2',
           [1] string[] CS$0$0000)
  IL_0000:  newobj     instance void Test.Program/'<>c__DisplayClass1'::.ctor()
  IL_0005:  stloc.0
```

Which you can see the first line in the routine creates the `Program` object. Why the compiler decided to put that line inside the try/catch is beyond me.

**EDIT**

Digging a little deeper, changing your program to this:

```
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] one;

        try
        {
            // 1. Hit F10 to step into debugging.
            one = new string[] { "1" }; //2. Drag arrow to this
            // 3. Hit f5.
            Enumerable.Range(1, 1)
                .Where(x => one.Contains(x.ToString()));
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Console.Write("BOOM!");
        }
    }
```

Results in working code. Examining the IL, you can see that the instance creation was moved outside the try:

```
  .locals init ([0] class [mscorlib]System.Exception exception,
           [1] class [mscorlib]System.Func`2<int32,bool> 'CS$<>9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate1',
           [2] class Test.Program/'<>c__DisplayClass2' 'CS$<>8__locals3',
           [3] string[] CS$0$0000)
  IL_0000:  ldnull
  IL_0001:  stloc.1
  IL_0002:  newobj     instance void Test.Program/'<>c__DisplayClass2'::.ctor()
  IL_0007:  stloc.2
  IL_0008:  nop
  .try
  {
```

The compiler was nice enough to move the creation of the string array from outside the try to inside the try, so skipping that line still results in a valid object. The code works, so I'm guessing that the `NullReferenceException` really is the instance of the `Program` class.

Comment: I had various working and not-working versions of the code as I was distilling the error. I will certainly be using the disassembly to answer these questions in future.

Answer (score 1):

Long story short when you drag the arrow there's no memory allocation for the `one` variable so basically i think you're getting a Null Pointer Reference in a pretty wrapper

Funny think is that the same thing happens in .NET4.0, NET4.5, VS2013 and VS2015 RC which is supposed to have a different compiler (Roslyn)
Have a look a images bellow

My assembly is pretty bad so i won't try to pretend to understand everything that's going on.

**Start here**

[image]

**Normal execution**

[image]

I've highlighted the changes your array is null but it exists, also you can see the registry changes.

Not take a look at what happens when i drag

[image]

Your variable isn't even there(and also almost look at the registry changes), so i'm guessing that you've just skipped over a few few lines or assembly.

Now you can also take a look at the memory and see there's nothing there.

**Memory when i step trough**

[image]

Empty space but it's there.

**If i step trough it even has values**

[image]

**Memory when i drag**

[image]

Nothing there.

Considering the fact that i tried with 2 versions of .NET and 2 different compilers i think it must be a VisualStudio problem you could post this bug [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/visualstudio) it might get patched in a future update.